# memory error when reading in large input file in python

Tags: python, memory

I have a file that's 100,000,000 lines long, each line containing a random integer between 1 and 999. I have the following code which needs to read it and store it in a list:

```
L100000000 = []
inf = open("100000000.txt", "r")
inputData = inf.readlines()
for line in inputData:
    L1000000.append(int(line.rstrip()))
data.append(L100000000)
```

And this is the error I get when running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\witcher\Documents\NJIT\CS 288\mergesort.py", line 114, in <module>
    inputData = inf.readlines()
MemoryError
```

I've never had this issue before, how is this resolved in Python?

Comment: Process the file a line at a time rather than trying to read the whole thing at once.

Comment: Note that even if you parse the lines one by one, your resulting list of 100M integers will still consume approximately 400MB of memory. This may or may not be possible.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart mmm probably significantly more. On a 64 bit system, just the underlying array of pointers will be 800mb. Now, the `int` objects themselves will be about 28 bytes. However, Python caches small ints, so actually, (256/999) of them will be cached. Assuming a uniform distribution,I'd guesstimate `(28*(1-256/999) + 8)*100000000*1e-9` gigabytes, or 2.88 gigabytes